# Limited functions calculator

Tags: calculation-puzzle, strategy

There's a calculator with 10 functions exp, square, sin, cos, tan and their inverses. 
We need to convert 0 to 1 to 2 to 3 to -3.
Note: Addition, subtraction, multiplication and division are not there

Comment: Is the calculator in degrees or radians?

Comment: Does the calculator allow complex intermediate values?

Comment: This is a fascinating broken-calculator variation and makes me wonder about the smallest subset of push-button functions (perhaps standard calculator keys, perhaps not) that could produce any rational number

Answer (score 4):

<sup>(This began as combined answers of
[Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44154/18129)
and
[humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44153/18129),
and has progressed nicely.)</sup>

As spoilered as it gets:

> **0**  
>  <kbd>$\cos    $</kbd>   **1**  
>  <kbd>$\exp    $</kbd> $e$
>  <kbd>$   x^2  $</kbd> $e^2$
>  <kbd>$\log    $</kbd>   **2**  
>  <kbd>$\exp    $</kbd> $e^2$
>  <kbd>$\surd   $</kbd> $e$
>  <kbd>$\surd   $</kbd> $e^{1/2}$
>  <kbd>$\log    $</kbd> $\frac{1}{2}$
>  <kbd>$\cos^{-1}$</kbd> $\frac{\pi}{3}$
>  <kbd>$\tan    $</kbd> $\sqrt{3}$
>  <kbd>$x^2     $</kbd>   **3**  
>  <kbd>$  e^x   $</kbd> $e^3$
>  <kbd>$\tan^{-1}$</kbd> $\alpha ~ \small \big( \dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} = \dfrac{e^3}1 \big)$
>  <kbd>$\sin     $</kbd> $\small \dfrac{e^3}{\sqrt{1+e^6}}$
>  <kbd>$\cos^{-1}$</kbd> $\beta  ~ \small \big( \beta = \frac\pi2{-}\alpha \, , ~ \sin\beta = \dfrac1{\sqrt{1+e^6}} \big)$
>  <kbd>$\tan     $</kbd> $\small \dfrac1{e^3}$
>  <kbd>$\log     $</kbd>   **−3**

Comment: Do we even need the description of the intermediate functions anymore, seeing as the short form doesn't use $x+1$ anymore, and only uses $-x$ in one place?

Comment: Cleaned up, @2012rcampion. Thanks to your improvement, the buttons might well fit on a single line by themselves now.

Comment: Spoilertagging doesn't really work with that keyboard-style formatting: the only thing that's hidden is the result of each operation, which is easy to deduce anyway since we know the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the given functions:

<kbd>$    e^x $</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm  ln $</kbd>
<kbd>$    x^2 $</kbd>
<kbd>$   \surd$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm  sin$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm asin$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm  cos$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm acos$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm  tan$</kbd>
<kbd>$\rm atan$</kbd>

These functions can be contructed from those:

<kbd>$  |x|  $</kbd>   $ \, : ~~~ x $
<kbd>$   x^2 $</kbd>  $x^2$
<kbd>$  \surd$</kbd>  $|x|$
$\raise-1ex\strut$

<kbd>$  1{+}x $</kbd>  $ : ~~~ x $
<kbd>$   \surd$</kbd>  $\surd x$
<kbd>$\rm atan$</kbd>  $ \theta $ ($\tan \theta = \surd x$)
<kbd>$\rm  cos$</kbd>  $ \frac1{\sqrt{1+x}} $
<kbd>$\rm  ln $</kbd>  $ -\ln \sqrt{1+x} $

      
<kbd>$  |x|   $ (as constructed)</kbd>  $ \ln \sqrt{1+x} $
<kbd>$  e^x   $</kbd>  $ \sqrt{1+x} $
<kbd>$   x^2  $</kbd>  $1+x$

This gets to 3:

> **0**
>  <kbd>$  1{+}x $</kbd> **1**
>  <kbd>$  1{+}x $</kbd> **2**
>  <kbd>$  1{+}x $</kbd> **3**

To convert 3 to -3,
see [Gareth McCaughan’s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44154/18129)
or the [combined wiki post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/44155/18129).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the missing piece in humn's otherwise excellent answer: how to get from 3 to -3.

> First of all, it's enough to get from exp(3) to exp(-3); in other words, we need to take a reciprocal. It's then enough to get from atan(exp(3)) to atan(exp(-3)), which means getting from $x$ to $\pi/2-x$ for some $x$. But we can do that by taking sin and then acos.

So the specific sequence of operations is:

> exp atan sin acos tan log.

Answer (score 0):

- 0 to 1:

  > $\exp(0)=1$.
- 1 to 2:

  > $\cos^2(\tan^{-1}(1))=\frac{1}{1^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}$; take the inverse to get $2$.
- 2 to 3:

  > $\tan^2(\cos^{-1}(2^{-1}))=\Big(\frac{1}{2^{-1}}\Big)^2-1=3$.
- 3 to -3:

  > $\log((\exp(3))^{-1})=-3$.

Comment: Just to clarify: $\cos^2(x)=\left(\cos(x)\right)^2$, not $\cos(\cos(x))$, right?

Comment: How do you perform 1/x?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yep. Squaring is allowed, according to the question, even though multiplication isn't.

Comment: @humn Taking inverses is allowed according to the question.

Comment: Inverses of the functions given